# Getting phone number from android mobile phone

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Which commands should I use in order to get the sim phone number from an Android mobile phone?
Exploring the sample of phone dialer i found "PhoneDialerService.GetCarrier" but with no option for getting mobile's phone number.

Answer (score 2):

If the device uses only one sim card use :

```
TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phoneNumber = phoneManager.getLine1Number();
```

In case the device uses two or more sim cards, use:

```
TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String simSerialNumber = phoneManager.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Don't forget the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Note that there isn't any guaranteed solution. This won't work(might return null) on every device/country because phone numbers are not physically stored on all SIM cards. The best solution is to ask the user to enter his/her phone number once and store it, and ask if number is ported/changed.

Comment: Alternative how can I get the serial number of the phone or the IMEI number? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Furthermore, where inside the code should I put the above permission?

Comment: Just call "phoneManager.getDeviceId()" to retrieve the IMEI number. Place the permission inside your xml manifest not java code

Comment: Do you also know how to get IMSI number? Thank you again

Comment: No it didn't work. It didn't accept Telephony manager variable & furthermore getapplicationcontext. I found the solution from Remy Lebeau (https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=604553). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Have you noticed this is Java code and we use Pascal!?

Comment: If phoneManager.getLine1Number() returns a number, can it be trusted as a valid number for the phone?  Is it fairly common for a phone to have multiple SIM cards?

Comment: @JohnWard yes the number can be trusted as valid and most android phones have multiple sim cards but it's best if you ask the suer for the number as it might be ported or changed.